# How to set the focus of custom tab to remain static in Excel addin api using js

Tags: static, focus, excel-addins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSGam.png)

Hi,

I have created an excel addin project using custom tab ribbon that loads at very last tab but the focus shifts to Home tab each time I perform any operation using that custom tab.
I want the custom tab ribbon focus position to remain fixed each time I perform any operation.

I want the default focus to be remain on SystenicsXL